# How to know to upgrade my pod when a container is updated?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I have a pod with 3 containers (ca, cb, cc).

This container is owned by TeamA. Team A creates and owns ca.the other two containers are developed by two other teams. TeamB for cb and TeamC for cc.

Both cb and cc also run independently (outside the TeamA pod) as services within this same cluster.

How can TeamA pod find out when cb or cc deploy a newer version in the cluster and how can we ensure that it triggers a refresh?

As you may have guesses cb and cc are services that ca relies on heavily and they are also services in their own right.

Is there a way to ensure that TeamA pod keeps cb and cc updated whenever TeamB and TeamC deploy new versions to the cluster?

Answer (score 3):

This is not a task for Kubernetes. You should configure that in your CI/CD tool. For example, whenever a new commit is pushed to service A, it will first trigger the pipeline for A, and then trigger corresponding pipelines for services B and C. Every popular CI/CD system has this ability and this is how it's normally done.

Proper CI/CD tests will also protect you from mistakes. If service A update breaks compatibility with B and C, your pipeline should fail and notify you about that.

Answer (score 0):

There's no one specific answer. https://github.com/jetstack/version-checker provides a metrics/alerting approach. Numerous kubectl plugins give a CLI reporting approach. Stuff like https://fluxcd.io/docs/guides/image-update/ can do upgrades automatically within certain parameters.

Or maybe just actually talk to your coworkers, this is both a technological and social problem and you'll need answers from both sides.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will check these out. Speaking with coworkers is an option but I am seeking an automated  approach.